# Posicionamento de imagem com z-index

Tags: css, z-index

Estou a tentar posicionar uma caixa de texto sobre uma imagem através do z índex, par ficar com algo deste estilo: 
http://postimg.org/image/an6lkq9gf/

Neste momento o texto aparece depois da imagem (visto que esta se encontra numa div com 100% de largura). Eu queria que o texto aparecesse sobreposto à imagem.

O que estou a fazer mal? Obrigado

O meu código:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
#intro {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    padding-right:3%;
    padding-top:3%;
    padding-bottom:3%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    position:relative;
    z-index:50;
}
.txt_ilustracao {
display:block;
width:38%;
margin: 7% 3% 3% 7%;
float:right;
color:black;
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
padding:5%;
position:relative;
z-index:100;
}
.txt_ilustracao1 {
font-size:2.5em;
margin-top: 10%;
margin-bottom:3%;
text-align:center;
}
.txt_ilustracao2 {
font-size:1.8em;
margin-top:9%;
text-align:center;
}
</style>

     <div id="intro"><img src="IMGS/index_fundo_pb.jpg"></div>

          <div class="txt_ilustracao">

                      <div class="txt_ilustracao1">
                    asdfgcvhbjklçjh erdtfyguhijopoçlikujhtgrfed<br>
                    asdfgcvhbjklçjh erdtfyguhijopoçlikujhtgrfed <br>
                    asdfgcvhbjklçjh erdtfyguhijopoçlikujhtgrfed</div>
                        <div class="txt_ilustracao2">asdfgcvhbjklçjh         erdtfyguhijopoçlikujhtgrfed
                       asdfgcvhbjklçjh erdtfyguhijopoçlikujhtgrfed.<br><br>
                      asdfgcvhbjklçjh erdtfyguhijopoçlikujhtgrfed</div>


   </div> <!-- intro -->
```

Comment: Já tentou com `background-image`?

Comment: Sim, mas neste caso interessava me que fosse com o z-index. Obrigado

Comment: E o que está acontecendo?

Comment: Neste momento o texto aparece depois da imagem (visto que esta se encontra numa div com 100% de largura). 

Eu queria que o texto aparecesse sobreposto à imagem.

Comment: Na classe css `.txt_ilustracao`, troque o `position:relative` por `position:absolute` e teste.

Comment: Assim já deu. Obrigado Rafael! Agora o único problema é a caixa de texto. Queria que ela ficasse alinhada do lado direito (atribui-lhe o float:right). No entanto ela está "presa" do lado esquerdo.

Alguma sugestão?
Obrigado

Comment: Pra usar o z-index as classes não devem estar uma dentro da outra, usa uma div pro fundo e uma pra caixa, o conteudo da caixa tu deixa dentro da div caixa mesmo, aí o texto vai flutuar junto com a caixa.

Comment: Para que a caixa de texto fique alinhada ao lado direito use `right: 0px;`

Comment: Muito obrigado Carlos, funcionou! :D

Answer (score 1):

Bastam alguns ajustes simples, vamos lá:

1. Em seu código html, a `<div class="txt_ilustracao">` passa a ser filha da `<div id="intro">`. Com isso, controlaremos o posicionamento da legenda da foto, respeitando os limites(dimensões) de sua `imagem`. Segue código abaixo:

---

### HTML

```html
<div id="intro">
  <img src="IMGS/index_fundo_pb.jpg" width="750" height="600">
  <div class="txt_ilustracao">
    <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum.</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. Em seu código css, faça os ajustes abaixo:

---

### CSS

```css
#intro {
  position: relative; /* Para que a posição da legenda(txt_ilustracao), dependa das dimensões de #intro */
  float: left; /* Para se ajustar às dimensões da img */
}
.txt_ilustracao {
  width:38%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  position: absolute; /* Para flutuar por cima da div#intro e tê-la como referência para 'caminharmos' pelos eixos x e y */
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  right: 30px; /* Alinha o box à direita com uma distância de 30px do limite da div#intro */
  top: 50%; /* Coloca o box na posição 0 do eixo y da div#intro */
  margin-top: -25%; /* Recua 25% da altura para que o box fique centralizado no eixo y da div#intro. Independente da altura da imagem ou do box de legenda, o elemento sempre estará centralizado no eixo y. */
}
.txt_ilustracao h2 {
  /* Propriedades do título */
}
.txt_ilustracao p {
  /* Propriedades do parágrafo */
}
```

---

Veja como ficou na [Demonstração](http://plnkr.co/edit/5ootLRfSpYS289hYXD4W?p=preview).